# Beginner Python Code Issue: Accumulator Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, accumulator

I am a beginner programmer and I am working on an assignment that requires me to do nested loops as part of a finance operation. I have written most of the code and the numbers work according (such as interest and such), however the issue arises when I try print out the savings summary for the years given.

```
import math

def main():

    #This will be hardcoded values for the years running, savings amount and annual interest             and calculate the monthly interest rate

    savingsAmount = 500
    annualInterest = 0.12
    yearsRunning = 2

    monthlyInterest = annualInterest / 12

    #This will state the accumulator variables for totals of investment balance (month), savings (YTD), and interest earned (YTD)

    totalInvestBal = 0
    totalSavings = 500
    totalInterest = 0

    #This will begin the accumulator loop process

    for i in range (1, yearsRunning + 1):
        print "Savings Schedule for Year", i,":"
        print "Month    Interest    Amount  Balance"
        for i in range (1, 13):
            totalInterest = monthlyInterest * totalInvestBal
            totalInvestBal = totalSavings + totalInterest + totalInvestBal
            totalSavings = totalSavings
            print i, round(totalInterest,2), round(totalSavings,2), round(totalInvestBal,2)         
        print 
        #i becomes 12 here so we need another answer.
        print "Savings summary for year", (need a new way of saying the year here),":"
        print "Total amount saved:", totalSavings
        print "Total interest earned:", totalInterest
        print "End of year balance:", totalInvestBal


main()
```

Since the "i" loop index variable is updated to 12, I can place that as the year. I am working from year 1 up and I need the savings summary to be from year 1 and up as well. How would that be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the second loop variable form `i` to anything else (e.g. `k`):

```
for i in range (1, yearsRunning + 1):
    print
    print "Savings Schedule for Year", i,":"
    print "Month    Interest    Amount  Balance"
    for k in range (1, 13):
        totalInterest = monthlyInterest * totalInvestBal
        totalInvestBal = totalSavings + totalInterest + totalInvestBal
        totalSavings = totalSavings
        print k, round(totalInterest,2), round(totalSavings,2), round(totalInvestBal,2)         
    print 
    #IF WE KEEP ONLY i IT becomes 12 here so we need another -> VARIABLE!!!!! for example K!!.
    print "Savings summary for year %s:" %(i) #use this " words words %s words" %(variable name)
    print "Total amount saved:", totalSavings
    print "Total interest earned:", totalInterest
    print "End of year balance:", totalInvestBal
```

Comment: You are welcome! I use %s instead of d% or i% but you should use one of these for integer see [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). You should learn it as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I added some \t 's to your code- they denote printing a tab for your output so that the output lines up better.

```
def main():

    #This will be hardcoded values for the years running, savings amount and annual interest             and calculate the monthly interest rate

    savingsAmount = 500
    annualInterest = 0.12
    yearsRunning = 2

    monthlyInterest = annualInterest / 12

    #This will state the accumulator variables for totals of investment balance (month), savings (YTD), and interest earned (YTD)

    totalInvestBal = 0
    totalSavings = 500
    totalInterest = 0

    #This will begin the accumulator loop process

    for i in range (1, yearsRunning + 1):
        print
        print "Savings Schedule for Year", i,":"
        print "Month \tInterest \tAmount \tBalance"
        for i in range (1, 13):
            totalInterest = monthlyInterest * totalInvestBal
            totalInvestBal = totalSavings + totalInterest + totalInvestBal
            totalSavings = totalSavings
            print i, "\t", round(totalInterest,2), "\t\t",  round(totalSavings,2), "\t", round(totalInvestBal,2)         
        print 
        #i becomes 12 here so we need another answer.
        print "Savings summary for year" #, (need a new way of saying the year here),":"
        print "Total amount saved:", totalSavings
        print "Total interest earned:", totalInterest
        print "End of year balance:", totalInvestBal


main()
```

Since this is an assignment, I'll point out some errors I see and let you try to fix them. If you look at the output:

```
Savings Schedule for Year 1 :
Month   Interest    Amount  Balance
1   0.0         500.0   500.0
2   5.0         500.0   1005.0
3   10.05       500.0   1515.05
4   15.15       500.0   2030.2
5   20.3        500.0   2550.5
6   25.51       500.0   3076.01
7   30.76       500.0   3606.77
8   36.07       500.0   4142.84
9   41.43       500.0   4684.26
10  46.84       500.0   5231.11
11  52.31       500.0   5783.42
12  57.83       500.0   6341.25

Savings summary for year
Total amount saved: 500
Total interest earned: 57.8341733327
End of year balance: 6341.2515066
```

your balance isn't correct, look at this line of code for a solution:

```
totalInvestBal = totalSavings + totalInterest + totalInvestBal
```

For your question, the way I'm interpreting it is that you want to have a separate interest-earned value in just the timeframe of a year, after the first year. So the output that I think you want for year 2 is (assuming you fix the end of year balances):

```
Savings Schedule for Year 2 :
Month   Interest    Amount  Balance
1   63.41       500.0   6904.66
2   69.05       500.0   7473.71
3   74.74       500.0   8048.45
4   80.48       500.0   8628.93
5   86.29       500.0   9215.22
6   92.15       500.0   9807.37
7   98.07       500.0   10405.45
8   104.05      500.0   11009.5
9   110.1       500.0   11619.6
10  116.2       500.0   12235.79
11  122.36      500.0   12858.15
12  128.58      500.0   13486.73

Savings summary for year
Total amount saved: 500
Total interest earned: 70.74733
End of year balance: 13486.7324266
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Although I see your point, the professor wanted us to update the investment balance each time interest is accumulated. Although the numbers appear to be out of place, the addition that he wanted us to do is to have the previous balance updated with the interest accumulated. It's strange, but that's what he asked for. But this is wonderful, thanks for your help! I got it to work!